# WSO2 Identity server - Unable to add new user with "error while persisting user : renault"

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I created a user (testinguser) in WSO2 identity server version 5.10.0 and deleted them afterwards cause I had created them in the primary user store yet I wanted to add them to the secondary user store (MySQL).

However, when I try to add the user with any name, I am getting the error `Could not add user wso2is/renault. Error: Error while persisting user : renault` yet renault is not created as a user

I also see this in the logs

```
[2020-04-25 00:18:19,727] [2f2cdf35-4c34-447e-9ffa-c14490a7e101] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} - Error while persisting user : renault org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAcc
```

[image: error-message-on-user-creation]

Comment: What's the ***User Store Manager Class*** option you selected when adding the new user store?

Comment: Can you add more entries from the error log?

Comment: _**User Store Manager Class**_ is org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager

Comment: More from the error log is on the link below as it cannot fit here. Link is 

[https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/491cbae6c510f65614d7e747c9263fed](https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/491cbae6c510f65614d7e747c9263fed)

Comment: Select `UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager` as the ***User Store Manager Class*** and check whether the problem is still there or not.

Comment: Thanks @sumedhe, this worked fine.
Please add it as an answer and I mark this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `JDBCUserStoreManager` as the **User Store Manager Class** when adding the new user store. Select `UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager` instead.

As described in the documentation,

> *From WSO2 IS 5.10.0 onwards, all user store managers have `UniqueID` included as part of the user store manager name.*
>
> *The user store managers that do not have `UniqueID` as part of the user store manager name are only available for backward compatibility
>   purposes and can only be used if you are migrating from a previous
>   version of WSO2 Identity Server.*

Refer: [Configuring Secondary User Stores](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores)